# How to observe a related ViewSource?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

In a WPF XAML I have

```
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Key="aViewSource"
    d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my1:TableA, CreateList=True}" />
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Key="anotherViewSource"
    Source="{Binding Path=ANOTHER, Source={StaticResource aViewSource}}" />
```

In the xaml.cs I have

```
var aViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)this.FindResource("aViewSource");
var tableA = new ObservableCollection<TableA>(
    this.entities.TableA
        .Where(predicate)
        .Take(10)
        .ToList());
tableA.CollectionChanged += this.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler;
fibrasViewSource.Source = tableA;
```

How can I observe `anotherViewSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned ViewSource altogether since I saw no advantages on using it.